# Getting intermittent "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" editing chat room description

Tags: bug, chat

I'm attempting to update the [C# chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) description and roughly 80% of the time I'm getting:

[image: Oops! Something Bad Happened!]

I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but I was originally attempting to use markdown link formatting (`[like this](https://www.example.com)`). However, it's also failed when I wasn't including markdown, so it might just be a red herring. It has worked a few times (but never when including the above markdown).

Comment: What's the full message including markdown that you're trying to add? It could be character limit you're hitting

Comment: Well, the logged exception is "The message is too long." so... Maybe the description is too long?

Comment: I just did some testing - sometimes it fails with the same description that has also succeeded. Character limit might be a factor but I don't think it's the only thing. See starting [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45012111#45012111) - I started by appending 123456790, working my way down, and then working my way up. Heading down it failed until 1, heading back up it succeeded until 1234.

Comment: At any rate, the description is overdue for a trim.